# $L_3$ conserved on geodesics?

Tags: conservation-laws, coordinate-systems, geodesics

Let's take a simple $E^3$ space with coordinates $(x,y,z)$ and metric tensor
$$ g = \mathrm{d} x \otimes \mathrm{d} x + \mathrm{d} y \otimes \mathrm{d} y + \mathrm{d} z \otimes \mathrm{d} z $$

The geodesics are straight lines
$\vec{r} = \vec{r}_0 + \vec{v}_0 t$. Let's take a very specific straight line
$$ \begin{aligned} x (t) &= 1 \\ y (t) &= t \\ z (t) &= 0 \end{aligned} $$

There are many conserved quantities, let's take for example $L_z = x \dot{y} - y \dot{x}$ (verifiably conserved).

Let's now make new coordinates with the transformation
$$ \begin{aligned} x &= r \sin \theta \cos \phi \\ y &= r \sin \theta \sin \phi \\ z &= r \cos \theta \end{aligned} $$
for which
$$ g = \mathrm{d} r \otimes \mathrm{d} r + r^2 \mathrm{d} \theta \otimes \mathrm{d} \theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta \, \mathrm{d} \phi \otimes \mathrm{d} \phi $$

And take the same line, just in the new coordinates, that becomes
$$ \begin{aligned} r (t) &= \sqrt{x^2 (t) + y^2 (t)} = \sqrt{1 + t^2} \\ \theta (t) &= \pi / 2 \\ \phi (t) &= \arctan(y(t)/x(t)) = \arctan(t) \end{aligned} $$

The same quantity $L_z$ now becomes $\dot{\phi}$. As we can see, $\dot{\phi}$ is not a constant, because
$$ \dot{\phi} (t) = \frac{1}{1 + t^2} $$

What went wrong?

- is the notion of a geodesic dependent on coordinates (that would be kinda icky, since coordinates are totally arbitrary, which would mean that geodesics of a certain space are totally arbitrary)?
- is $L_z$ no longer conserved, so the symmetries and conserved quantities depend on choice of coordinates (again, icky, ...)?
- is $\dot{\phi}$ not equal to $L_z$? I obtained it from the Killing vector in Cartesian coordinates, $\xi = x e_y - y e_x$, which transforms into $e_\phi$.
- does the conservation of $L_z$ depend on reparametrization of the geodesic? If I take $y (t) = \tan (t)$ instead, I get $\phi (t) = 1$, which is conserved. Does that mean that symmetries and conservation laws depend on reparametrisation of a geodetic? Maybe there's some caveat with Killing vectors and reparametrization.

Edit: as Michael suggested, the problem might be in mixing unit vectors and coordinate basis. To be clear, what I meant was that the Killing vector in *coordinate basis* in Cartesian is $x \partial_y - y \partial_x$, and the Killing vector in *coordinate basis* in spherical is $\partial_\phi$. However, to get the conserved variable, we have to do
$$
\xi \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{r}}{\mathrm{d} t}
$$
and in spherical coordinates, that $\cdot$ actually carries the additional baggage in terms of the components of the metric tensor, so specifically
$$
L_z = (r^2 \sin^2 \theta) \frac{\mathrm{d} \phi}{\mathrm{d} t}
$$

So for my specific example, I have $L_z = r^2 \dot{\phi} = \left( \sqrt{1 + t^2} \right)^2 / (1 + t^2) = 1$. Hooray!

Comment: Is $L_z$ not $r^2\dot{\phi}$?

Comment: $L_z = r^2 \dot{\phi}$, which is nice and conserved.  I suspect your error is in mixing up the covariant and the contravariant components of the Killing vector, or possible in mixing up the coordinate basis with the orthonormal basis.  I'm about to go into class now, but I'll write up a longer answer if nobody else does by the time I can get back to this.

Comment: Michael, I think you're right! Thank you for saving my day, I almost thought that math is broken haha!

Comment: My pleasure—and sorry I didn't get back to this sooner.  I would encourage you to post your resolution as an answer to your own question using the controls at the bottom of the page (this is perfectly fine on StackExchange) and then mark it as "resolved".